# Regex using angularjs ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs, regex

I want to use angularjs ng-pattern.

Wich regex can i, using four characters, to allow the first just being a number, the second being a number **OR** a letter, the third being only a number and the fourth being only a number.

I try this one but  it only allows letters on the second character.

```
[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: `[A-Z]` matches an uppercase letter, if you add `0-9` into the class, it will also match digits. Do not forget `^` at the start to make sure the whole pattern is anchored and matches an entire string.

Comment: And remove all `{1}`, they are redundant, see [Avoid Common Problems and Pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: I try : [0-9][A-Z]|[0-9][A-Z][0-9]{2}$[0-9]{2}$ but did not match using regex101 to validate this example : 1a23

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/SPEKLQ/2

Comment: Now i see what is needed to work, i can enclose a set of rules inside [ and ]